# Comparing intervals across multiple time series in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, posixct

I have two concurrent time series `A` and `B`, both containing events defined by start and end times - here is a sample:

```
A.df <- structure(list(A.eventid = 1:53,
                       A.start = structure(c(1563219814.52, 1563219852.37, 1563220313.16, 1563220472.66, 1563220704.35, 1563220879.51, 1563221108.24, 1563221158.33, 1563221387.43, 1563221400.7, 1563221602.34, 1563221828.33, 1563222165.52, 1563222314.2, 1563222557.28, 1563222669.44, 1563222905.52, 1563223091.62, 1563223237.19, 1563223273.64, 1563223580.14, 1563223908.66, 1563224093.27, 1563224497.41, 1563224554.64, 1563224705.57, 1563225011.55, 1563225192.59, 1563225305.14, 1563225414.38, 1563225432.21, 1563225898.61, 1563226034.51, 1563226110.18, 1563226206.49, 1563226528.13, 1563226570.18, 1563226788.53, 1563227026.21, 1563227502.2, 1563227709.3, 1563227832.51, 1563228127.44, 1563228188.4, 1563228293.59, 1563228558.39, 1563228680.32, 1563228819.44, 1563229208.51, 1563229282.14, 1563229528.52, 1563229959.21, 1563230268.65), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
                       A.end = structure(c(1563219846.43, 1563220304.39, 1563220470.68, 1563220702.37, 1563220877.5, 1563221102.18, 1563221151.47, 1563221379.63, 1563221389.22, 1563221600.32, 1563221819.27, 1563222157.29, 1563222312.23, 1563222555.25, 1563222667.42, 1563222894.56, 1563223079.44, 1563223230.39, 1563223273.24, 1563223578.14, 1563223900.48, 1563224089.24, 1563224493.45, 1563224550.37, 1563224699.47, 1563225005.13, 1563225188.17, 1563225293.21, 1563225412.17, 1563225417.46, 1563225894.44, 1563226025.2, 1563226108.13, 1563226204.37, 1563226517.59, 1563226562.41, 1563226780.59, 1563227022.28, 1563227493.57, 1563227705.52, 1563227830.38, 1563228125.49, 1563228184.21, 1563228286.39, 1563228546.47, 1563228677.67, 1563228816.5, 1563229198.68, 1563229273.54, 1563229526.53, 1563229952.57, 1563230257.16, 1563230742.25), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))),
                       row.names = 1:53, class = "data.frame")

B.df <- structure(list(B.eventid = 1:52,
                       B.start = structure(c(1563221811.888, 1563222153.835, 1563222156.013, 1563222220.14, 1563222289.692, 1563222305.607, 1563222611.565, 1563222631.139, 1563222636.867, 1563222763.565, 1563222774.301, 1563222848.507, 1563222849.957, 1563222853.513, 1563223225.656, 1563223302.539, 1563223326.153, 1563223328.934, 1563223590.144, 1563223592.904, 1563224035.038, 1563224692.704, 1563226451.642, 1563226454.731, 1563226819.701, 1563226824.685, 1563227278.677, 1563227770.247, 1563227773.907, 1563227800.529, 1563227804.663, 1563227809.749, 1563227813.237, 1563227819.043, 1563227829.781, 1563227973.727, 1563229396.472, 1563229454.515, 1563229473.079, 1563229488.669, 1563229521.413, 1563229542.954, 1563229553.595, 1563229565.988, 1563229569.095, 1563229618.857, 1563229791.585, 1563229936.355, 1563230339.141, 1563230734.677, 1563231667.173, 1563231978.567), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
                       B.end = structure(c(1563221815.058, 1563222154.295, 1563222158.633, 1563222222.07, 1563222289.872, 1563222308.617, 1563222614.265, 1563222633.509, 1563222640.367, 1563222769.045, 1563222774.801, 1563222848.677, 1563222850.237, 1563222856.103, 1563223226.166, 1563223305.339, 1563223328.763, 1563223333.234, 1563223591.454, 1563223593.084, 1563224043.618, 1563224695.234, 1563226454.622, 1563226456.771, 1563226822.551, 1563226827.225, 1563227282.067, 1563227771.787, 1563227774.477, 1563227802.199, 1563227806.653, 1563227811.569, 1563227817.897, 1563227823.643, 1563227830.351, 1563227978.177, 1563229401.282, 1563229457.905, 1563229478.359, 1563229492.439, 1563229527.723, 1563229545.694, 1563229558.975, 1563229568.658, 1563229571.255, 1563229621.117, 1563229792.055, 1563229952.055, 1563230344.351, 1563230739.647, 1563231672.983, 1563231979.987), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))),
                       row.names = 1:52, class = "data.frame")
```

Events in series `A` are longer, while events in `B` are shorter.

I've drawn a schematic to help explain:

[image]

For each `A` event during which ≥ 4 `B` events occur, I'd like to compare (also shown on the schematic):

`X = the mean interval between B events occurring during the A event`

with

`Y = the interval between the last B event occuring during the A event, and the first B event occurring after the A event`

My issues are with the calculation of `X` and `Y`.

To calculate `X`, I tried using `foverlaps` to group `B` events by the `A` events in which they occur. But, this excludes `B` events occurring within gaps between A events.

Also, my attempts to calculate the mean intervals between grouped `B` events using `mutate` and `lag` failed, as I couldn't restrict `lag` to working only within the groups (i.e. it calculated intervals between groups as well).

Finally, I'm not sure how to efficiently identify the start/end of the `Y` interval to calculate its duration.

I was thinking my R/coding was improving, but this has me floundering a bit - any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your B-events are in chronological order, do not overlap eachother and only fall within a maximum of 1 A.event...

Explanation and in-between-output are commented in code below.

I could not verify the output, since you provided no desired/expected output in your question. Results look plausible to me on first glance..

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A.df); setDT(B.df)
#get time to next B
B.df[, time.to.next.B := shift(B.start, type = "lead") - B.end ][]
#get A-event that the B-events falls into
B.df[ A.df, 
      A.eventid := i.A.eventid, 
      on = .(B.start >= A.start, B.end <= A.end )][]
#    B.eventid             B.start               B.end time.to.next.B A.eventid
# 1:         1 2019-07-15 22:16:51 2019-07-15 22:16:55   338.777 secs        11
# 2:         2 2019-07-15 22:22:33 2019-07-15 22:22:34     1.718 secs        12
# 3:         3 2019-07-15 22:22:36 2019-07-15 22:22:38    61.507 secs        NA
# 4:         4 2019-07-15 22:23:40 2019-07-15 22:23:42    67.622 secs        13
# 5:         5 2019-07-15 22:24:49 2019-07-15 22:24:49    15.735 secs        13
# 6:         6 2019-07-15 22:25:05 2019-07-15 22:25:08   302.948 secs        13
#             ...

#summarise by A.eventid, get number of B-events, and B.eventid of last B-event
#only get A-eventis's with 4 or more B-events
ans <- B.df[ !is.na( A.eventid), 
             .( B.events = .N, 
                last.B.eventid = max( B.eventid ),
                next.B.eventid = max( B.eventid ) + 1,
                mean.B.interval.within.A = mean( time.to.next.B[ B.eventid != max( B.eventid ) ] ) ), 
             by = .(A.eventid) ][ B.events >= 4, ]
#    A.eventid B.events last.B.eventid next.B.eventid mean.B.interval.within.A
# 1:        16        5             14             15           20.879500 secs
# 2:        41        8             35             36            6.097714 secs
# 3:        50        4             40             41           26.239000 secs
# 4:        51        7             48             49           62.953500 secs

#now find the needed intervals using an update joins
ans[ B.df, start_time := i.B.end,   on = .(last.B.eventid = B.eventid)]
ans[ B.df, end_time   := i.B.start, on = .(next.B.eventid = B.eventid)]
#    A.eventid B.events last.B.eventid next.B.eventid mean.B.interval.within.A          start_time            end_time
# 1:        16        5             14             15           20.879500 secs 2019-07-15 22:34:16 2019-07-15 22:40:25
# 2:        41        8             35             36            6.097714 secs 2019-07-15 23:57:10 2019-07-15 23:59:33
# 3:        50        4             40             41           26.239000 secs 2019-07-16 00:24:52 2019-07-16 00:25:21
# 4:        51        7             48             49           62.953500 secs 2019-07-16 00:32:32 2019-07-16 00:38:59

X <- ans$mean.B.interval.within.A
# Time differences in secs
# [1] 20.879500  6.097714 26.239000 62.953500
Y <- ans$end_time - ans$start_time
# Time differences in secs
# [1] 369.553 143.376  28.974 387.086
```

Comment: revised code, for a complete answer... please verify output..

Comment: Thanks @Wimpel! This works great! But, it highlighted that `B` events extending past the end of `A` events are not associated with that `A` event ID (the code instead gives an NA). On reflection, I think they should contribute to the mean.

I'm still working to understand your code (I haven't used `data.table` much), but thought it would be possible replace `B.end <= A.end` (on line 8 of your code) with something like `B.end <= shift(A.start, type = "lead")`. But, that gives an error?

Comment: Also, I'd like to have the option to filter out `Y` values that extend into the next `Y` event . For example, if on the schematic above,`Y1` extended past `Y2` into the 3rd event of Series `A`.

I'm sure with a bit of time I can work both issues out, but if you have any hints I'd be glad to hear them!

Comment: If B can extend beyond A.end (but has to start befone A.end !), then you can simply drop the restriction `B.end <= A.end` and replace it with a start-condition, so that part would become `on = .(B.start >= A.start, B.start <= A.end )`.  I don't get how Y1 can extend beyond the second A, since it always ends with on the first B in the second A. But maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks again! Sorry I didn't explain my 2nd question well. Taking `A.eventid 16` as an example, it's last `B` event ends at `21:34:16.102`, and the next  `B` event starts at `21:40:25.655`. But, `A.eventid 18` starts at `21:38:11.61`. So, in this case, there are no `B` events in `A.eventid 17`, and interval `Y` extends beyond into `A.eventid 18`. It's these cases, where the 'Y' interval between `B` events extends beyond the next `A` event, that I'd like to filter out. Hopefully that's more clear?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to come up with a possible solution, minus the part of the average calculation, which should be obvious. First I renamed the column names, which makes it easier to join the data sets:

```
A.df = A.df %>% 
  rename_all(funs(str_replace(., "A.", ""))) %>% 
  mutate(type="A")
B.df = B.df %>%
  rename_all(funs(str_replace(., "B.", ""))) %>% 
  mutate(type="B")
```

Then the overall data, sorted by time, is:

```
data = bind_rows(A.df, B.df) %>% 
  arrange(start)
```

Now I add a column showing the time stamp of the last start of an `A` event. Forward filling this value will show for each event the time of the last `A` event.

```
data = data %>%
  mutate(last.A.start=ifelse(type=='A', start, NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(last.A.start)
```

Finally, the `A` events can be removed. As long as the  `last.A.start` is the same, the `B` events belong to the same `A` event. Based on these information `x` and `y` can be calculated.

```
data = data %>%
  filter(type == "B") %>%
  mutate(
    duration=end-start,  # Not needed.
    delta=start - lag(end),
    sameA=(last.A.start == lag(last.A.start)),
    x=ifelse(sameA, delta, NA),
    y=ifelse(sameA, NA, delta)
  )
```

Does this help?
Bests, M